# How to pass data from text file to ansible playbook?

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat

I want to have text file which contains name and password

```
   name: "Peter", "Joe", "Mark"
   password: "smith", "biden", "garyy"
```

And I have playbook like this

```
---
- hosts: myhosts
  become: yes
  remote_user: root1
  become_user: root
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{key}}"
  tasks:

  - name: Create users
    user: name="{{item.name}}" shell=/bin/bash home="/srv/{{item.name}}" groups=root generate_ssh_key=yes ssh_key_bits=2048
    loop:  "{{ lookup('file', 'userspasswd.txt', wantList=True)| list }}"
  - name: Set password to users
    shell: echo "{{item.name}}:{{item.password}}" | sudo chpasswd
    no_log: True
    loop:  "{{ lookup('file', 'userspasswd.txt', wantList=True)| list  }}"
```

I am getting error like this

```
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/root1/Documents/ansiblekernel/main.yml': line 12, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Create users\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Is there any correct way of doing this? Cause I am new to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat userspasswd.txt
name: "Peter", "Joe", "Mark"
password: "smith", "biden", "garyy"
```

---

Neither *`wantList=True`* nor the filter *`list`* will help you to parse the file because it's not a valid [YAML](https://www.yamllint.com/). If you can't change the structure of the file you'll have to parse it on your own.

Declare the variables

```yaml
  userspasswd_lines:  "{{ lookup('file', 'userspasswd.txt').splitlines() }}"
  userspasswd_values: "{{ userspasswd_lines|
                          map('split', ':')|
                          map('last')|
                          map('regex_replace', '\"', '')|
                          map('split', ',')|
                          map('map', 'trim')|
                          list }}"
  userspasswd_dict: "{{ dict(userspasswd_values.0|
                             zip(userspasswd_values.1)) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  userspasswd_lines:
  - 'name: "Peter", "Joe", "Mark"'
  - 'password: "smith", "biden", "garyy"'

  userspasswd_values:
  - - Peter
    - Joe
    - Mark
  - - smith
    - biden
    - garyy

  userspasswd_dict:
    Joe: biden
    Mark: garyy
    Peter: smith
```

---

Update. Simplify the parsing. You get valid YAML when you remove quotes. The declarations below give the same dictionary

```yaml
  quote: '"'
  up: "{{ lookup('file', 'userspasswd.txt')|replace(quote, '')|from_yaml }}"
  up_dict: "{{ dict(up.name.split(',')|map('trim')|
                    zip(up.password.split(',')|map('trim'))) }}"
```

---

Iterate the dictionary. Test it

```yaml
    - name: Create users
      debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item }}
          shell: /bin/bash
          home: /srv/{{ item }}
          groups: root
          generate_ssh_key: yes
          ssh_key_bits: 2048
      loop:  "{{ userspasswd_dict.keys()|list }}"

    - name: Set password to users
      debug:
        msg: 'echo "{{ item.key }}:{{ item.value}}" | sudo chpasswd'
      loop:  "{{ userspasswd_dict|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [Create users] **************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item=Peter) => 
  msg: |-
    name: Peter
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /srv/Peter
    groups: root
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
ok: [test_11] => (item=Joe) => 
  msg: |-
    name: Joe
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /srv/Joe
    groups: root
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
ok: [test_11] => (item=Mark) => 
  msg: |-
    name: Mark
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /srv/Mark
    groups: root
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048

TASK [Set password to users] *****************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item={'key': 'Peter', 'value': 'smith'}) => 
  msg: echo "Peter:smith" | sudo chpasswd
ok: [test_11] => (item={'key': 'Joe', 'value': 'biden'}) => 
  msg: echo "Joe:biden" | sudo chpasswd
ok: [test_11] => (item={'key': 'Mark', 'value': 'garyy'}) => 
  msg: echo "Mark:garyy" | sudo chpasswd
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: myhosts

  vars:

    userspasswd_lines:  "{{ lookup('file', 'userspasswd.txt').splitlines() }}"
    userspasswd_values: "{{ userspasswd_lines|
                            map('split', ':')|
                            map('last')|
                            map('regex_replace', '\"', '')|
                            map('split', ',')|
                            map('map', 'trim')|
                            list }}"
    userspasswd_dict: "{{ dict(userspasswd_values.0|
                               zip(userspasswd_values.1)) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: userspasswd_lines
        - debug:
            var: userspasswd_values
        - debug:
            var: userspasswd_dict
      run_once: true

    - name: Create users
      debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item }}
          shell: /bin/bash
          home: /srv/{{ item }}
          groups: root
          generate_ssh_key: yes
          ssh_key_bits: 2048
      loop:  "{{ userspasswd_dict.keys()|list }}"

    - name: Set password to users
      debug:
        msg: 'echo "{{ item.key }}:{{ item.value}}" | sudo chpasswd'
      loop:  "{{ userspasswd_dict|dict2items }}"
```